Finding the Relationship Between $∠GCF$ and $α$ in a Rhombus with an Isosceles Triangle
I am working on a problem involving a rhombus $ABCD$, where point $E$ lies on side $BC$. Triangle $AEF$ is an isosceles triangle with $AE = EF$, and $∠AEF = ∠ABC = α$, where $α$ is at least $90°$. Line $AF$ intersects line $CD$ at point $G$. I need to find the relationship between angle $∠GCF$ and $α$.
Rhombus Properties: In a rhombus, all sides are equal and opposite angles are equal. The diagonals intersect at right angles and bisect the vertex angles.
Given that $α ≥ 90°$, which indicates that angle $α$ is at least a right angle, I am particularly interested in how this impacts the angle $∠GCF$ at the intersection.
How does angle $∠GCF$ relate to $α$ in this geometric configuration? Any insights or geometric proofs are greatly appreciated.


What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? This information can help answerers avoid wasting time (theirs and yours) duplicating your effort, explaining you things you already understand, or using techniques beyond your current skill level. ... If my quick-and-dirty analysis is correct (my GeoGebra sketch seems to confirm it), then we have $$\angle GCF = \dfrac32\angle ABC - 90^\circ$$

Thank you for your insights. I value your feedback on the angle calculations and appreciate you sharing your findings. Thank you once again for your assistance. I’m eager to learn more and correct my understanding based on your analysis.

If we define  as some point on the ray opposite $\overrightarrow{CB}$, then we can say more simply that
$$\angle HCF=\frac12\angle BCD$$ Provided the result is independent of the position of $E$, the above value appears immediately from examining the case of $E=C$. So, "all you have to do" is prove that the result really is independent of the position of $E$.

Thank you for your guidance. It seems that the degree of ∠DCF is not affected by the position of point E along segment BC, and I have not thought of a method to prove this. Can you provide a method related to this issue? There is another solution to this problem: by connecting AC and noting that triangle ABE is similar to triangle ACF, we find that angle ACF equals angle ABC, which is α. Thus, angle GCF equals angle ACF minus angle ACD, which is α - (90 - 1/2α) = 3/2α - 90.

Changing some notation, I let $\angle ABC=2\beta$ and $\angle DCB=2\gamma$; note that $\beta+\gamma=90^\circ$. Also, define $p:=|AB|$ and $q:=|BE|$.


Extend $\overline{BC}$ by length $q$ to a point $H$, so that $|AB|=|EH|=p$. Since $\angle BAE\cong\angle CEF$ (why?), we have $\triangle ABE\cong\triangle EHF$ by SAS.

We also have $|CH|=|FH|=q$, making $\triangle CHF$ isosceles.

We conclude that $$\angle HCF\;=\;\gamma\;=\;\frac12\angle BCD$$ or, with a bit of angle arithmetic, $$\angle DCF\;=\;\angle HCD-\angle HCF\;=\;2\beta-\gamma\;=\;\frac32\angle ABC-90^\circ$$



If you look properly,
$$\angle AFE=\angle FAE=\frac{180°-\angle FEA}{2}=\frac{180°-\alpha}{2}$$
Thus for $\triangle GCF$,
$$\angle GCF+\angle GFC+\angle CGF=180°$$
OR
$$\angle GCF + \frac{180°-\alpha}{2}+\angle EFC+\angle CGF= 180°$$
Now $\angle BAG=\angle BAE+\angle EAF=\angle CGF$(corresponding angles)
So finally
$$\angle GCF + \frac{180°-\alpha}{2}+\angle BAE+\angle EFC+ \angle EAF= 180°$$
$$\implies \angle GCF+180°-\alpha+\angle BAE+\angle EFC=180°$$
$$\implies \angle GCF +\angle BAE+ \angle EFC= \alpha$$

The angle ∠GFC does not seem to equal ($(180 - \alpha) / 2$).

@OthS modified my answer now. Still I'm trying to remove any one of them 3 angles. Are there any other problems?

There seems to be no mistake.

I seem to be missing something. There remain two unspecified angles in addition to the one sought in this answer?

Let $a=\angle BAE=\angle CAF$. As $|AB|=k|AC|$, we have
$$a|AB|=ak|AC|$$
and by the sine rule, therefore
$$\angle AEB |AE|=k\angle CFA|AF|$$
Then we have $\triangle ABE\sim\triangle ACF$ by the power series expansion of the loci and angles.

One effective method to address the problem involves a geometric construction:

Constructing Line AC: Start by connecting point A to point C in the rhombus. This line will play a crucial role in our subsequent geometric analysis.

Identifying Similar Triangles: Observe that triangle ABE is similar to triangle ACF. This similarity is crucial as it implies that corresponding angles in these triangles are equal.

Equating Angles: Due to the similarity between triangles ABE and ACF, we can conclude that angle ACF is equal to angle ABC. Given that angle ABC is given as α, angle ACF must also be α.

Calculating Angle GCF: To find angle GCF, consider the angle difference at point C. Angle GCF is calculated as angle ACF minus angle ACD. Given that angle ACD (the angle between line AC and line CD) is half of the angle opposite to it in the rhombus, which is ($90^\circ - \frac{1}{2}\alpha$), the calculation follows:


$\text{Angle GCF} = \alpha - \left(90^\circ - \frac{1}{2}\alpha\right) = \frac{3}{2}\alpha - 90^\circ.$


How are you deducing $\triangle ABE\sim\triangle ACF$? It's true, but I don't see how you get there. (Maybe it's obvious, and I've been distracted by other parts of the figure.)

In isosceles triangles ABC and AEF, the vertex angles are both α. Therefore, triangle ABC is similar to triangle AEF. This means angle BAC equals angle EAF, and the ratio AF/AC equals AE/AB. Consequently, angle BAE equals angle CAF, and the ratio AF/AE equals AC/AB. Thus, triangle ABE is similar to triangle ACF.

Whether the explanation is reliable？

I didn't check through all that ---too much having to scroll up to the figure and back--- but it seems plausible. :) ... In any case, it's probably better to include your reasoning argument explicitly, rather than simply "observing" the similarity.
